# 2 lists inside one panel in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

How to have 2 lists in one single panel in sencha touch 2?
I can see the first list if i use

```
layout:'card'
```

I tried :

```
 layout: {
       type: 'vbox',
       align: 'stretch'
    }
```

Please let me know how can i have 2 lists inside the same panel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [flex config](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-flex) on each of your list.

You can see and example below here : [Sencha Fiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Fc0Vn#2E9R2)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

create panel with vbox layout inside it create two panel with fit layout and put every list into respective panle

try this method

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the above method is not working for me. what i can see is only blank screen.

Comment: `Ext.define('Proj.view.myPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config:{ layout:'vbox',
    items:[  {xtype:'panel',
              layout:'fit',
                items:[ {xtype:'list',
                         ....
                        }]
               }, {xtype:'panel',
              layout:'fit',
                items:[ {xtype:'list',
                         ....
                        }]
               }]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Akshatha you can try this into your `Ext.Panel`,

```
...
layout: {
     type: 'hbox',
     align: 'stretch'
 },
 items: [
     {
      xtype: 'list',
      width: '40%',
      flex: 1,
      styleHtmlContent: true,
      ...
     },
     {
      xtype: 'list',
      width: '60%',
      flex: 0.5,
      styleHtmlContent: true,
      ...
     },
 ]
 ...
```

You can define the `width` of `Panel` and you have `Ext.List`.

I hope help you. :)